# oAuth and twitter sign in requests via REST API

Tags: rest, twitter, oauth

I have an public application that wants to post from a private Twitter user's account.

A perfect example of this is: http://www.usabchallenge.com/

In the above example, you choose your 5 players and then click the Twitter button below and it will bring you to the `https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=YOUR_TOKEN` screen.

From reading the Twitter documentation - it seems I want a "sign in with Twitter button" which will grant me access to their account and when I have access I will then be able to post on their behalf.

I'm befuddled at the flow of this process. I can read it on Twitter's documentation but I'm not connecting the dots.

Quoted from Twitter's *Browser Sign In Flow* page. I numbered the steps for ease of reading.

```
1. The application renders a “Sign in with Twitter” link or button.
2. The user clicks the sign in button.
3. The current web browser is redirected to Twitter (or a new browser is opened and directed to Twitter).
4. The user completes a login and authorization step at Twitter if needed.
5. Twitter redirects back to an URL under the application’s control, passing authorization information for the user.
```

Steps 1 and 2 are self explanatory.

Step 3 - Do I set an href attribute or action on the button itself? How do I get to this page?

Step 4 is that the user clicks on the button on that api.twitter page where it says `Authorize YOUR_APPLICATION to use your account?`

Step 5 is the `oauth_callback` parameter you provided in the `oauth/request_token` api call.

So my 2 questions are:

How do I direct someone to the `https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=YOUR_TOKEN` screen from the sign in button? href? action? is there a default code for the button?

Also, where do I make this `oauth/request_token` call that provides the callback to get me to step 5? It makes sense that it would be requested once the user clicks the sign in button, but contradicting that is the fact that the sign in button takes the user to  `https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=YOUR_TOKEN` rather than somewhere where I would be able to make a call to the REST API.

For what it's worth - I have been using [this link](https://dev.twitter.com/web/sign-in) (as well as many other pages in their documentation) for reference.

And I'm using [codebird](https://github.com/jublonet/codebird-php) to connect to their REST API which has been working wonderfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 3 : It's this part of code which redirect your user to Twitter:

```
// redirect to auth website
  $auth_url = $cb->oauth_authorize();
  header('Location: ' . $auth_url);
  die();
```

I don't know what you use with PHP but if you have templates, you can pass the $auth_url in parameter to display it in your href instead of changing the location of your current page. You can also create an ajax call to a function that returns you this url. (personally i made a popup)

Step 4 : Exactly

Step 5 : I separated the second part of the code, in a file 'callback.php' (callback url i defined in Twitter point to this file) This way i can handle errors and redirections properly. 
Define it here also :

```
$reply = $cb->oauth_requestToken(['oauth_callback' => 'http://' .$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ]);
```